# Two 24" displayed vertically in Ubuntu

Tags: display, xorg, xrandr

I just got two 24 inch monitors, and want them to display vertically side by side, where the screens are placed horizontally relative to each other, but the screens are rotated vertically.  I got one to but can't figure out the command to get them both vertical and displaying.

xorg.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    SubSection "Display"
        Virtual 3840 1200
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
EndSection


xrandr:

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 3840 x 1200
VGA connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
TMDS-1 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1
```

any clue on the command to make them vertical?

Comment: ITYM 24" monitors ? Unless these are the truly huge monitors that you find at sports events etc ?

Comment: Clarify "vertically side by side". Do you mean vertically top-to-bottom or horizontally side-by-side?

Comment: I mean the monitors are left and right of eachother, but the screens are rotated vertically... so I'd need to rotate the output by 90 degrees on both.  And yes I meant 24'', thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nv driver, add this line at the bottom of the "Device" section:

```
Option "Rotate" "CW"
```

It should look similar to:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Generic Video Card"
    Driver      "nv"
    Option      "Rotate" "CW"
EndSection
```

Use CCW for Counter ClockWise. Reboot and see if it works.

If this doesn't work, add this line at the bottom of the "Device" section:

```
Option "RandRRotation" "On"
```

reboot, and see if the screen and rotate button is available at: `system` > `preferences` > `screen resolution`.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my xorg.conf file:

```
SubSection "Display"
        Virtual 2400 1920
    EndSubSection
```

I then ran these three commands in the terminal:

```
xrandr --output TMDS-1 --rotate left
xrandr --output VGA --rotate left
xrandr --output VGA --left-of TMDS-1
```

Comment: This will only work until a reboot... You'll have to run every time at boot I think.